# Convert datetime in form of "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" in "%Y-%m-%d %H"

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I need to convert my column of datetimes in specific format,  `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` in `"%Y-%m-%d %H"`.

For example:

```
library(lubridate)

#input
dates <- as_datetime(c("2018-06-22 18:19:04", "2018-06-22 19:58:04","2018-06-22 19:30:08", "2018-06-22 16:46:00", "2018-06-22 16:45:04"))

#output
dates_mod <- as_datetime(c("2018-06-22 18:00:00", "2018-06-22 19:00:00","2018-06-22 19:00:00", "2018-06-22 16:00:00", "2018-06-22 16:00:00"))
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @ClaudH i tried six different ways! :(

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
> trunc(dates, "hours")
[1] "2018-06-22 18:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 19:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 19:00:00 UTC"
[4] "2018-06-22 16:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 16:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: in addition, you can get any custom format using `format` (more exactly, `format.POSIXct` ), see its help file

Answer (score 0):

This also work:

```
lubridate::floor_date(dates,"hours")
# [1] "2018-06-22 18:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 19:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 19:00:00 UTC"
# [4] "2018-06-22 16:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 16:00:00 UTC"
```

`floor_date` is similar to `trunc.Date` but you can do some other neat things like `floor_date (dates,"3 hours")` to round by time range.

It also supports much more time units, the full list being (`?floor_date`):

> second, minute, hour, day, week, month, bimonth, quarter, season,
>   halfyear and year

While trunc supports (`?trunc.Date`):

> second, minute, hour, day, month or year

using `format`

```
format.Date(dates,"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00 %Z")
# [1] "2018-06-22 18:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 19:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 19:00:00 UTC"
# [4] "2018-06-22 16:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 16:00:00 UTC"
```

And some hackish solution that you really shouldn't use, but it showcases nicely `ymd_h`

```
lubridate::ymd_h(gsub("......$","",dates))
# [1] "2018-06-22 18:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 19:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 19:00:00 UTC"
# [4] "2018-06-22 16:00:00 UTC" "2018-06-22 16:00:00 UTC"
```